# How to alias joins in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

In my app I want to create a named scope to use in queries across the app that gets data from a has_many association. I run into issues when elsewhere I :include that same association, leading to mysql errors

```
Mysql::Error: Not unique table/alias: 'foo'
```

Here is what my named scope looks like:

```
named_scope :single_foo, :joins => :foo, :group => "foo.blip_id", :having => "count(foo.blip_id) = 1"
```

How can I update my :joins statement to make an alias for foo so that in queries as below I don't have unique table errors?

```
Blip.single_foo.find(:all, :include => [ :foo ], :conditions => (......))
```

Also, bonus points if somebody can guide me to a simpler named scope, I want to only select Blips that have a single Foo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to alias. The :include => [ :foo ] can be taken out of the later query because it is already included in the :joins call of the single_foo named scope. So all I needed my query to be was this:

```
Blip.single_foo.find(:all, :conditions => (......))
```